# Can't insert data to mysql database from android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, database

Hey I am trying to insert data to my sql data base and I cant figure out why it isn't working, when I run the php script on the host alone its working but when I try to do it from the android app it just doesn't do nothing I couldn't find the problem so I thought you guys might help me

here it the android code:

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String insertUrl = "http://localhost/insert.php";

        club_name = params[1];
        String publisher_name = params[2];
       String club_contact = params[3];
       String club_location = params[4];
       String club_hours = params[5];
       String club_age = params[6];
       String club_description = params[7];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(insertUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(club_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("number","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(publisher_name,"UTF-8");
                  //  URLEncoder.encode("publisher_phone","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(club_contact,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                   // URLEncoder.encode("location","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(club_location,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                   // URLEncoder.encode("hour_open","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(club_hours,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                   // URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(club_age,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                   // URLEncoder.encode("description","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(club_description,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();



        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Party has been posted!";
    }
```

and the php file:

```
<?php
require "connection.php";

$club_name = $_POST["club_name"];
$publisher_name = $_POST["publisher_name"];
$publisher_phone = $_POST["publisher_phone"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
$hour_open = $_POST["hour_open"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$description = $_POST["description"];

$sql = "insert into apps(club_name,publisher_name,publisher_phone,location,hour_open,age,description) values ('$club_name','$publisher_name','$publisher_phone','$location','$hour_open','$age','$description')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

?>
```

connection php:

```
<?php
$db_name = "ori";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$server_name = "localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);

if($conn)
{
    //echo "connects";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use PDO or sanitize those strings. Your app is wide open for SQL injection. Have you verified that $conn is actually connecting to the database? What does your connection.php look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: I really went through every line searching for an error and I just couldn't find what's wrong with the code.. I mean the php is fine I'm sure but something in the android code doesn't work and I can't figure out what..

Comment: "Going through every line" as in looking at it?  That's not using a debugger though it's a good thing to do.  Did you read Joe C's link and go through the steps in that article?

Comment: @JoeC Nice article, I bookmarked it.